# How can we implement pinch zoom in list of images in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

I am implementing an Imageviewer using QML that is based on Listview whose delegate are the images. To be noted the image gets displayed on the whole screen. I need to include the feature pinch zoom that will help in zoom in the image. Please suggest any good source or how to proceed examples.

Answer (score 1):

I created a demo for pinch zoom, zooming the `rect` by two touch points.

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 1000
    height: 1000
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    MultiPointTouchArea {
        id: multiPoint
        anchors.fill: parent
        touchPoints: [
            TouchPoint { id: point1 },
            TouchPoint { id: point2 }
        ]
        property real factor: 1
        property bool isReleased: false // ignore the TouchUpdate after released
        onTouchUpdated: {
            if(isReleased){
                isReleased = false
                return
            }
            if(point1.x != 0 && point2.x != 0){
                var s = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(point1.x - point2.x, 2) + Math.pow(point1.y - point2.y, 2)) /
                        Math.sqrt(Math.pow(point1.startX - point2.startX, 2) + Math.pow(point1.startY - point2.startY, 2))
                rect.scale = s * factor
            }
        }
        onReleased: {
            factor = rect.scale
            isReleased = true
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 200; height: 200
        color: "green"
    }
}
```

Update:
Also created a C++ `QQuickItem` module for pinch zoom in [Github](https://github.com/arkceajin/PinchZoomItem).

Comment: I came across PinchArea that is provide in Qt. Does the above implementation has any relation to PinchArea?

Comment: Also can MultiPointTouchArea can be used inside MouseArea? Will it get confused with the onreleased event of both elements?

Comment: @Shailendra it does not relate to `PinchArea` only depends on `MultiPointTouchArea`, mouse release event can also trigger the `MultiPointTouchArea`, why you want to put it inside `MouseArea`? For customizing pinch zoom please take a look the demo on Github.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I finally went with using PinchArea provided by Qt for the above implementation.
[PinchArea](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-touchinteraction-pincharea-flickresize-qml.html)